# Como fazer para fazer a autenticação do usuário quando ele curtir a pagina no Facebook?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html5, facebook

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que o usuário tenha acesso ao site a partir do momento que ele curtir a pagina no Facebook?